# When running my spark job, I get this error: id: <app-name>: No such user

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hue

I have a simple spark application where when I deploy, I always seem to get a non-fatal hadoop error as follows:

```
17/09/01 14:13:41 WARN security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: unable to return groups for user my-username
PartialGroupNameException The user name 'my-username' is not found. id: my-username: No such user
id: my-username: No such user 
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.resolvePartialGroupNames(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:133)
```

Could anyone point me into the reason why this error is showing up in the Spark logs? Any insight on this would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You most likely already read the links I will give you but in any case :

[Error on a cluster](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/203518997--Massive-number-of-cannot-find-name-for-group-ID-errors-found-in-the-NameNode-log-MapReduce-cluser-performance-was-impacted)

[Same error with CLoudera](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/HDFS-usermod-G/td-p/23515)

> This problem happens because the user who summited the jobs has a group ID which cannot be recognized by the hadoop cluster. Since Maprecue keeps checking and complaining about this problem, the cluster performance slowed down.
>
> Fix:
>
> Add a group name and user ID for that user in /etc/group on the host
>   where the job was submitted.

Another solution proposed :

> Both the user and the groups need to exist on the NameNode host
>   operating system:

```
sudo useradd my-username
sudo usermod -G developer my-username
```

> If you don't want the user to be able to log in to the NameNode:
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -s /bin/falso my-username
> ```
>
> OR

```
sudo usermod -s /usr/bin/nologin my-username
```

Dunno if that can help you, hope that will but I don't think so !

Have a good day !